# Show View Controller in Tab Bar Controller From Another Tab Without Switching Tabs

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have four view controllers embedded in a Tab Bar Controller (as shown below). I want to show the profile view from the feed view, without switching the tab. Any suggestions would be great.

[image]

Comment: present view controller

Comment: ok, i've tried that, but it doesn't show the tabs in the destination view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to do is adding a **subview**

> Here is my code i have used in my project tested on Swift 2.0

```
 let tabBarController = self.sourceViewController as TabBarController
 let destinationController = self.destinationViewController as UIViewController

        for view in tabBarController.placeholderView.subviews as [UIView] {
            view.removeFromSuperview() // 1st remove from superview
        }

        // Add view to placeholder view
        tabBarController.currentViewController = destinationController
        tabBarController.placeholderView.addSubview(destinationController.view) // 2

        // Set autoresizing mask so it fits correctly
        tabBarController.placeholderView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        destinationController.view.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

        let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[v1]-0-|", options: .AlignAllTop, metrics: nil, views: ["v1": destinationController.view]) // 3

        tabBarController.placeholderView.addConstraints(horizontalConstraint)

        let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-0-[v1]-0-|", options: .AlignAllTop, metrics: nil, views: ["v1": destinationController.view]) // 3

        tabBarController.placeholderView.addConstraints(verticalConstraint)

        tabBarController.placeholderView.layoutIfNeeded() // 3
        destinationController.didMoveToParentViewController(tabBarController) // 4

    }
```

**Here is the Blog i have refer to when i was doing custom tabbar hope it will help you :**
http://swiftiostutorials.com/tutorial-custom-tabbar-storyboard/

Comment: How do you get the destinationController? I have the class, but how do I get the instance?

Comment: as your class of UITabBarcontroller

Comment: Oh sorry, it's just that I am not subclassing TabBarController in my implementation.

Comment: what is placeholder view? in the TabBarController

Comment: placeholder view is the view that holds all the view

Comment: Well, that variable is not defined in UITabBarController

Comment: without removing the current view .. how will you add the new subview?

Comment: I am trying to say that Xcode is having trouble finding the placeHolderView variable in my UITabBarController.

Comment: can you upload your code so we can give you the correct code which will work with your code .....

Comment: If you found my answer useful don't forget to upvote and accept the answer 